# Core Data add index to relationships?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

Is there a way to add an index to a relationship in an Entity? I can see that attributes can be indexed, but not on relationships. 
I have a large dataset and need to check which ones actually have or not a relationship object in a predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relationshipField = nil"]
```

So I thought that it would be a good idea to index that relationship.
So my question is, can there be ? And if not, is there a performance strategy for this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this manually but you don't need to because — empirically speaking — Core Data does it automatically where it can. So that means that 'to one' relationships are automatically given indexes. Check your SQLite store for names like `ZENTITY_ZRELATIONSHIP_INDEX` to see the proof.

There is no meaningful way to add an index for a 'to many' relationship so Core Data couldn't do that automatically or expose the option. SQLite's format for indices is just a list of rows sorted by the thing being indexed, into which it performs a binary search. It has no way of building such a structure for a multivalued column, and multivalued columns are how Core Data stores to-many links.

Disclaimer: of course, these are all implementation-specific observations that appear in my subjective experience to apply to the current implementation of Core Data. But as a general rule I think you could safely say that Core Data will optimise for relationship lookups as best as it can.

Comment: Confirmed, I opened the .sqlite file and there they were on the sqlite_master table. thanks!